# Wireless networking issue with Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I must say I am really new to the networking stuff and Linux (Ubuntu 8.10). I am unable to connect to my wireless network after running these commands to change the MAC address and run in monitor mode:

```
airmon-ng stop wlan0 
ifconfig wlan0 down
macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

The reason I did this is because I want to test how secure my wireless network is (first stopping and trying to change the MAC, and then using air-crack-ng).

Here is what I have tried to reconnect to my wireless network:

1. Firstly I think I should change wlan0 to where it was (especially the Mac address) with the following commands:

   ```
   ifconfig mon0 down
   ifconfig wlan0 down
   macchanger --mac 00:0e:9b:ab:56:19 # myoriginalMacAddress
   airmon-ng stop wlan0
   ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```
2. Secondly I tried to connect to my wireless network in my WICD but it failed at obtaining IP address after going through validating authentication. So I exited WICD and tried to do the same thing in terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "mywireless"
   $ sudo dhclient wlan0
   There is already a pid file /var/run/dhclient.pid with pid 23682
   killed old client process, removed PID file
   Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.1
   Copyright 2004-2008 Internet Systems Consortium.
   All rights reserved.
   For info, please visit http://www.isc.org/sw/dhcp/

   mon0: unknown hardware address type 803
   wmaster0: unknown hardware address type 801
   mon0: unknown hardware address type 803
   wmaster0: unknown hardware address type 801
   Listening on LPF/wlan0/00:0e:9b:ab:56:19
   Sending on   LPF/wlan0/00:0e:9b:ab:56:19
   Sending on   Socket/fallback
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
   DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1
   No DHCPOFFERS received.
   No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
   ```

Here is the ifconfig output of my network adapters if it can help:

```
$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:9f:8d:23:74  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x1800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:493002 (493.0 KB)  TX bytes:493002 (493.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:9b:ab:56:19  
          UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:576  Metric:1
          RX packets:1508929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:768144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:806027375 (806.0 MB)  TX bytes:78834873 (78.8 MB)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:9b:ab:56:19  
          inet addr:169.254.5.92  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:576  Metric:1

wmaster0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-0E-9B-CD-4E-18-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Does anyone know what my problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Linux/Unix are you running, because not all commands are the same for wireless?

Command:

$ cat /etc/*-release

And why are you stopping and trying  to spoof(change your MAC) before you connect to your wireless AP(access point)or wireless router, instead of just connecting to it?

This should only apply if you are planning to do some wireless pentest/auditing or to see 
 how secure your wireless network router/ap is.

ifconfig mon0 down
ifconfig wlan0 down
macchanger --mac 00:0e:9b:ab:56:19 # myoriginalMacAddress
airmon-ng stop wlan0
ifconfig wlan0 up

The reason you are having issues with you second command or (2) is cause of all the other unnecessary stuff you just did on number 1.

Comment: Thanks! I am using Ubuntu 8.10. Yes I want to test how secure my wireless network is (first stopping and trying to spoof(change your MAC), and then using air-crack-ng). Without the commands in (1), I cannot connect to my wireless network. So I think I should revert what I did with the Mac address and restart wlan0. That's my intention of (1). If (1) is wrong, could you please point out what is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you might want to try these guys from the Ubuntu Forums:

I highly recommend to start here if you want to learn about the commands and hardware (compatible wireless card)requirements for auditing a wireless network, based on your distro(distribution).

Registration is free and so is the help; in addition, to the fact that the help will be more specialized to your distro(distribution) as opposed to me or anyone here just giving your generic linux commands that might or might not work for your given distro.

Option one:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1015877

Option two: If you think you have the hardware verify below:

http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers

Once you have verified that you hardware(wireless card is indeed supported), we move to step three which is also optional.

Option three: Download

This:

http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/506235/30/0/threaded

OR

http://www.remote-exploit.org/backtrack_download.html

It's a live CD, and it's the fastest and most secure way to audit you wireless network:
It comes with Gerix-Wifi-Cracker; in addition, to Wepbuster another  tool to easily crack varisous type of Wireless routers (WPA and WEP).

If you are brave enough and have a backup and are not scared of messing up your linux box, you can also just install these tools using apt-get or synaptic.

The only difference is that with the tools you rarely have to change your card from Managed mode to Monitor mode, and do all the typing, since the tools will do that for you.

However, if you install you will be at the command line, and probably spending some time at the Ubuntu Forums. In addition if you break something or mess something up, you are probably going to have to fix it, unlike windows, unless if you have a backup or the time to be tinkering with breaking stuff and fixing, linux like Unix is a big time hogger especially for a beginner.